# Length of page is disturbed while hovering on images

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am facing a problem on my webpage, when I hover on the images the popups are shown in a good way, but the length of the page is disturbed it means the page length gets bubbled. I am using javascript for this task. Below is the codes; your suggestions would be appreciated:

```
<script>
function showfunction(id) {
    //alert(id);
    //document.getElementById(id).style.display="block";
    $("#" + id).css('display', 'block');
}

function hidefunction(id) {
    //alert(id);
    //document.getElementById(id).style.display="none";
    $("#" + id).css('display', 'none');
    //alert(a);
}
</script>
```

Here is the html code and the images are display inline:

```
<body>
    <ul style="list-style-type:none; width:647px; margin-top:-37px;">
        <li class="new_hire_list">
            <img class="grayscale" onmouseover="showfunction('div1')" onmouseout="hidefunction('div1')" src="images/pro_management.jpg" />
        </li>
        <li class="new_hire_list">
            <img class="grayscale" onmouseover="showfunction('div2')" onmouseout="hidefunction('div2')" src="images/commun.jpg" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Here are the divs which gets displayed on hover of the images:

```
<div id="div1" onmouseover="showfunction('div1')" onmouseout="hidefunction('div1')" class="content" style="">
    <span style="font-size:11px; color:#000000;">
        barun LoremIpsum dolor sit amet 
        LoremIpsum dolor sit ametLoremIpsum dolor sit ametLoremIpsum dolor sit
        ametLoremIpsum dolor sit ametLoremIpsum dolor sit ametLoremIpsum dolor sit        
        ametLoremIpsum dolor sit ametLoremIpsum dolor sit ametLoremIpsum dolor
 sit
    </span>
    <br/>
    <img src="images/More_details.jpg" />
 </div>
 <div id="div2" onmouseover="showfunction('div2')" onmouseout="hidefunction('div2')" class="content">
    <span style="font-size:11px; color:#000000;">
        LoremIpsum dolor sit amet LoremIpsum dolor sit
        ametLoremIpsum dolor sit ametLoremIpsum dolor sit ametLoremIpsum dolor sit
        ametLoremIpsum dolor sit ametLoremIpsum dolor sit ametLoremIpsum dolor sit
        ametLoremIpsum dolor sit ametLoremIpsum dolor sit
    </span>
    <br/>
    <img src="images/More_details.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Thank you sir I am so gladful for your involvement in my problem. Its really so appreciable. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `div`s are part of the page length. If you show/hide them, the browser resizes the page.

What you need is some static whitespace (an empty vertical box), big enough for the `div`s to appear in.

A simple solution would be to wrap the info `div`s in a `<div style="height: 200px;">...</div>`.

This wouldn't change and the page wouldn't jump.

Comment: Thank you sir I am so gladful for your involvement in my problem. Its really so appreciable. Thanks once again.